# navigation controller stack uses too much resources

Tags: ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

I am building an application that have an introduction at first when users do not login.
If they log in, when navigation controller will push to Home View Controller, but the Introduction View Controller is still in the stack and use a lot of resources. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the navigation controllers property to array holding ur homeview controller alone. Or set the home view controller as root of navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent it from being there necessarily as that is a function of how you associate your views.

If you are happy with your current transitions (UI) then you should add a bit of code after the transition has completed which gets the nav controller view controllers array, removes the first object (the login / intro VC) and saves the new array.

If you want to change the transitions then you could look at presenting the login / intro as a modal so that when it is dismissed it is automatically destroyed.

Comment: but removing object in view controllers array does not mean view controller memory will be freed, isnt it?

Comment: Unless something else is retaining it (which usually wouldn't be the case) then it will be deallocated.